# Why does my phone and fax p tags in the footer malign on apple mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile

Here's the link:
https://www.valleyconstructionsupply.com/

On apple devices the words "phone" and "fax" are on the right and their respective numbers are on the left.  I cannot figure out what is happening because on chrome when I inspect they are where they're supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the weirder things I've seen in a while! This looks as it should for me on Chrome for iOS, but on Safari on iOS, it's as you describe.  Your HTML is clean and simple, and the CSS that styles it doesn't do anything funky that would mess with the layout.  I could be missing something, but I truly don't see what that would be.  It's a hack, but I assume you're trying to get this out the door; thus I'd suggest forcing Safari not to mess with your layout by doing something like:

```
<p style="white-space: nowrap">Phone:&nbsp;(800)&nbsp;922-2082</p>
```

It's ugly, but it'll probably do the trick.  Safari is probably trying and failing to highlight the phone number so it's clickable to the Phone app, and messing up your layout in the process.  Literally can't think of why else this would be happening.

Comment: @ryanp That's truly, truly weird (and you're right, it still looks messed up for me on iOS Safari as well).  If I were you, I'd try something completely different and see what might trick Safari into acting like a normal non-broken browser - maybe wrap "Phone:" and the phone number in separate `span`s (or `div`s with `inline-block` display), or go old-school and lay the thing out in a `table` and see if Safari still feels like messing up your hard work!  This smells like a Safari "feature" (maybe to do with highlighting phone numbers) gone awry.

Comment: found a solution - I changed the width of the p element from 250px to 210 an that changed their format. but i cannot get them on the same line... at least they are better now, just on top of their numbers instead of next to them. This will work for now until I figure what the heck apple is doing

Comment: Whatever they’re doing, it’s some crazy stuff!